# Showing heterogenous data in a listview from two tables in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor, mergecursor

I have two totally unrelated tables Notes and Tasks. I need to show both of them together in a combined list view. To achieve this, the combined cursor given to list adapter should have a FULL OUTER JOIN of the two tables. 
I am not sure which of CursorJoiner/MergeCursor is the way to go.Can someone give some working example of how to achieve this?

(Changing the content provider is not possible. So I have to work with cursors.)

EDIT:
Also I need to be able to sort the items in a combined form. Notes has a subject column and Tasks has a title column. I want the combined cursor sorted alphabetically based on both of them.

Comment: Why you wouldn't just put JOIN in SQL query?

Comment: Sqlite doesn't support full outer join

Answer (score 0):

As full outer or right outer join is not supported in sqlite
and if you wana now about the CursorJoiner and CursorMerger  go through these link below

[When to use CursorJoiner / MatrixCursor / MergeCursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701545/when-to-use-cursorjoiner-matrixcursor-mergecursor][1])

**CursorJoiner**

If you need data from two or more  tables, the most straightforward thing to do is to use a SQL query that joins the two tables. However, sometimes you already have sources for two separate queries (such as a CursorLoader based on a ContentProvider), and you may wish to just re-use them, without creating a new query.This is where CursorJoiner comes in handy.

http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/android-advanced-cursors/

**MergeCursor**

MergeCursor allows you to present two or more cursors as a single cursor. You could get almost the same effect by doing a sql UNION query. However, MergeCursor allows you to have different columns in the various cursors, and still merge them.